# confusion between select and selected

Tags: grammar

> Scheduled Caste and Scheduled Tribe applicants are half as likely to get selected for a Ph.D.

why selected is used in above sentence why not select is used.

Answer (score 2):

The is the "get-passive".  It is a passive voice construction that is formed with "get + past-participle".  The tense is indicated by the tense of "get". The get passive is only used with "active" verbs, and so can indicated an active selection process. It also tends to be less formal than the "be-passive".

https://www.grammaring.com/the-passive-with-get

It is also an infinitive "to get selected".  The implied grammatical subject is "applicants" (or "scheduled caste... applicants") But in a passive phrase the grammatical subject is the functional object.  As there is no "by..." phrase, the functional subject is omitted.  From the wider context, the functional subject is the person who selects PhD students.

In an active clause it could be re-written

> People who select PhD students are half as likely to select Scheduled Caste and Scheduled Tribe applicants.

But the author wants the sentence to be about the applicants, not the people who select them, so has used a passive.

Comment: if get selected is passive then where is subject of it.

Comment: Do you mean the grammatical subject or the functional subject?  The grammatical subject is "applicants".  The function subject (by ....) is omitted